# PHP session regeneration security

Tags: php, security, session

I'm having a difficult time with PHP doing some very basic session security type of things:

- A new session ID should be generated when switching from a non-authenticated context to an   authenticated one
- A new session ID should be generated when switching from an authenticated context to a non-authenticated one

What I'd like to do is not only regenerate a session ID when switching contexts, but also immediately put something into the session (such as a FLASH) when switching those contexts. These three pages should hopefully clarify my expectations:

```
<?php
/* page1.php */
session_start();
# Just putting something in the session which I expect to
# not show up later
$_SESSION['INFO1'] = 'INFO1';
?>
<html>
<a href="page2.php">Page 2</a>
<?php print_r($_SESSION) ?>
</html>
```

So when this page is displayed, I expect to see `INFO1` show up. I also expect when I come back here NOT to see `INFO2` show up. If I don't already have a session ID, I expect to get one (I do).

```
<?php
# page2.php
session_destroy();
session_regenerate_id(TRUE);
$_SESSION['INFO2'] = 'From page 2';
session_write_close();
header('Location: page3.php');
exit;
?>
```

This would be most akin to a logout function - we invalidate the existing session by passing `TRUE` to `session_regenerate_id`. Also, I put something in the (presumably) **new** session - which may be like a FLASH - say "You've been logged out successfully.

```
#page3.php
<html>
<body>
<?php session_start(); ?>
<?php print_r($_SESSION); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

On this page, I'd **expect** two things to happen:

- The redirect from `page2.php` should have sent me a new session ID cookie (it did not)
- I'd expect for the `print_r` to print information from `INFO2`, and **not** from `INFO1`. It doesn't have information from `INFO1`, but does not include information from `INFO2`.

I've had very, very inconsistent results with `session_regenerate_id` and redirects. It seems like such a kludge to manually send that `Set-Cookie` header - but even if I didn't, `session_regenerate_id(TRUE)` should invalidate the old session ID anyhow - so even if the browser didn't for some reason get the new session ID, it wouldn't see any information in the session because the old session had been invalidated.

Has anybody else had experience with these sorts of issues? Is there a good way to work around these issues?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php) for `session_regenerate_id`, it sounds like the *contents of the session* are always preserved.  You're passing it a `TRUE` argument, but that only deletes the actual session file on disk; the values stored in it are kept in `$_SESSION` and then written to the new session.

So perhaps wipe it out manually:

```
$_SESSION = array();
```

Not sure why you aren't seeing the new cookie, though.  Where did you check, what did you see?

edit: The problem, as revealed by the OP in a comment below, appears to be that page2 never called `session_start` to load the first session.  Which produces the following:

```
<?php
    session_start();    # Load the old session
    session_destroy();  # Nuke it
    session_unset();    # Delete its contents
    session_start();    # Create a new session
    session_regenerate_id(TRUE);  # Ensure it has a new id
    $_SESSION['FLASH'] = "You've been logged out";
    session_write_close();  # Convince it to write
    header('Location: index.php');
?>
```

I have no idea if this is minimal.  Figuring out how much of it can be deleted is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: Uhh - right - adding a `session_destroy` to `page2` clears out the contents of the session, but the new content is still not added, and the new session ID is not sent.

I checked to see if a new session ID was sent by looking both in the webkit tools to see the current cookies for the site. Because I couldn't believe it wasn't sending a new cookie, I also checked with a MITM proxy - it's definitely not sending a new cookie.'

Comment: `session_destroy` _also_ only affects the file on disk.  It does not erase `$_SESSION`.  By creating a new session, you give PHP somewhere to store all that session data that's left over from the first session.  Try dumping `$_SESSION` after each line on page 2 and you should see this happening.

Comment: Hmm.  For the cookie problem, what happens if you drop the `session_write_close` call?  What happens if you drop the `header`+`exit` and just serve a page?

Comment: Thanks, @Eevee - I think between the two of us, we finally got it worked out:

  <?php
    session_start(); # To get the existing session
    session_destroy(); # Clear the session from persistence
    unset($_SESSION); # This is what I was missing - because we did a start, $_SESSION still had data
    session_start(); # Restart the session
    session_regenerate_id(TRUE); # Create a new session ID
    $_SESSION['FLASH'] = "You've been logged out";
    session_write_close(); # Because I've had bad luck with it persisting
    header('Location: index.php');
    ?>php

Comment: If you want the credit for the right answer and for others to be able to see it, post that code from above and I'll vote it up. It was the combination of `session_destroy` AND `unset($_SESSION)` which finally did the trick.

Comment: The PHP Manual [session_unset](http://www.php.net/manual/function.session-unset.php) mentions "Caution Do NOT unset the whole $_SESSION with `unset($_SESSION)`" rather use: "`$_SESSION = array();`" (when using later than PHP 4.0.6).